# Method in method in method c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods

Is it bad to have a lot of methods referring to each other, like the following example?

```
public void MainMethod()
{
   GetProducts();  
}

public void GetProducts()
{
   var _products = new Products();
   var productlist = _products.GetProductList;
   GetExcelFile(productlist);
}

public void GetExcelFile(List<product> productlist)
{
   var _getExcelFile = new GetExcelFile();
   var excelfile = _getExcelFile.GetExcelFileFromProductList(productlist);

   //create excel file and so on...
}
```

So I am creating a new method for every little action. It would be just as easy to call `GetProducts` from the `MainMethod` and do `all` actions in that method, but I think that isn't the way to create re-usable code.

The following tells me that there should be no more than 7 statements in a method:

[Only 7 statements in a method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137123/coding-guideline-methods-shouldnt-contain-more-than-7-statements)

**So the advantages of using methods with a minimal amount of code:**

- Code is re-usable
- Every task can get his own method

**The disadvantages of using methods with a minimal amount of code:**

- It's like spaghetti code
- You get: refer to refer and so on

**My question:**

Should my methods be bigger, or should I keep creating small methods, that do little and refer to a lot of other methods?

Comment: I don't believe in the so-called `Only 7 statements in a method`. We create a method if it will be re-used more than 1 time and if we need to pass some argument to change the input and get the corresponding output.

Comment: The 7 statements is a heuristic (not a hard rule), but still a good one. Whenever methods get behond 6 or 7 statements you should start looking more closely at those methods to see whether they still contain one level of abstraction. This doesn't mean that all methods can be short. There are always some methods that get bigger, such as methods that do object initialization (initialize 20 properties of an object), or methods that contain a large switch case statement (yes, they're still needed sometimes). But these methods are the exception to the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guideline is right. Methods should be small and you are doing the right thing be giving not only each operation its own method, but a well **defined name**. If those methods have a clear name, one responsibility and a clear intention (and don't forget to separate commands from queries), your code will not be spagetti. On top of that, try to order methods like a news article: most important methods on top of the file, methods with the most detail on the bottom. This way anyone else can start reading at the top and stop reading when they're bored (or have enough information).

I can advice you to get a copy of [Robert Martin's Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). There's no one in the industry who describes this more clearly than he does.

Comment: I think all the `related methods` should be placed near together, so that we can refer to one of them easily.

Comment: Thanks for the 'news article' tip, I think it is important to first use methods that cover a lot of basic actions and check which deeper method should be called from that basic method and not the other way around.

Comment: Aside from the __well defined name__ a method also provides a scope for its variables.

Answer (score 2):

The guideline is generally a good one, not so much for reuse, but for readability of your code.

Your example, though, is not a good one. What you're doing is basically creating a long list of methods where each one stops when you feel it's too long and calls another one to perform the rest of the operations.

I would follow more this kind of approach, where reading the main method tells you the "story" that your code needs to tell by steps and the detail of each step is in smaller methods.

```
public void MainMethod()
{
   var productlist=GetProducts();  
   string excelfile=GetExcelFile(productlist);

   // do something in the excel file
}

public List<product> GetProducts()
{
   var _products = new Products();
   return _products.GetProductList;
}

public string GetExcelFile(List<product> productlist)
{
   var _getExcelFile = new GetExcelFile();
   var excelfile = _getExcelFile.GetExcelFileFromProductList(productlist);

   return excelfile; 
}
```

Comment: I think this is a nice and clear way of coding as well, it is pretty easy to read, because you can just read the MainMethod and all returned values from values are stored in that method. The basic actions can be done easily this way, I'm still doubting if I should go with your way of writing or Steven's way. They both are very clear for reading. I will try to make a combination of the best parts:)

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: We're both saying the same thing, but Paolo (correctly) warns about splitting methods just to prevent getting them above 7. As you can see in Paolo's example, the `MainMethod` contains the most important information, so he (probably intentionally) grouped methods in the order they are read (like a news article).

Comment: @Steven Yeah you are both preferring small methods(which I think is best as well), giving the MainMethod a lot of information is indeed very easy for reading code. The way of refer to refer is also a good way, the difference is that the code will have more depth, the way I'm currently coding.

Comment: Personally, I rather see the `MainMethod` have no code except one method call to a method that exactly describes that is happening (assuming that the name of `MainMethod` is not descriptive enough and can't be changed). This way you start reading at the top (at `MainMethod`) and see right away what that method is doing. I'm not sure if `GetProducts` is descriptive enough, but that's up to you.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg I think the point is that each method should try to describe what it is doing in steps that have a comparable level of "detail". If your application is getting a list of products from a DB and building a list of excel files for each product, your MainMethod could say `{var prods=GetListOfProductsFromDB(); CreateExcelFiles(prods);}` Your GetListOfProductsFromDB could then tell the story of how you get the list of products from a DB, which is a deeper level of detail

Answer (score 0):

I don't really agree with '7 statements in a method'. A method can have dozens of statements, as long as the method performs a single function and the specific logic will only be used in one place, I don't really see the point of cutting it into parts just because some guyideline says so, it should be seperated based on what makes sense.

Re-use of code is good if it makes sense, but I don't think you should make everything everywhere re-usable, when you have no plans in the near future to actually re-use it. It increases the development time needlessly, it often makes the software more complex and harder to interpret then it needs to be, and (at least in my company) the majority of the code never gets re-used, and even if it is it still needs modifications in new products. Only the most generic parts of our codebase actually gets used in several applications without modifications for each product.

And I think that's fine.

Answer (score -1):

this is mostly opinion based question, but i'll tell you one thing:

**if you're not going to use a method from more then one place, it might be better not to create a method for that.**

you can use regions for clarity and you might not want a method that is larger then a full page, but not every 2-3 commands should get a method.

Comment: Bad bad bad! The main reason methods exist is for allowing humans to understand code, not to prevent code duplication. Your advice goes against everything we learned about code quality in the industry the past decade.

Comment: I also disagree. It is good to extract some statements that logically belong together to a method ***even*** if that method is only called from one place. There is absolutely nothing wrong with having a method which is only called from one location.

Comment: @Steven I think `allowing humans to understand code` and `re-use code` are **both** important. If as you said, we just need `comment` and `region separation`? yes, they are enough for the purpose of understanding code.

Comment: @KingKing: I've worked on code bases in the past where developers only created methods when needed for reuse. This is absolute pain when it comes to maintainability. I agree, both DRY and readability are important, because it all comes down to maintainability. I learned the last 10 years that big methods with lots of comments and regions are NOT maintainable.